# In Python - Parsing a response xml and finding a specific text vaule

Tags: python, xml, parsing, memory

I'm new to python and I'm having a particularly difficult time working with xml and python. The situation I have is this, I'm trying to count the number of times a word appears in an xml document. Simple enough, but the xml document is a response from a server. Is it possible to do this without writing to a file? It would be great trying to do it from memory.

Here is a sample xml code:

```
<xml>
  <title>Info</title>
    <foo>aldfj</foo>
      <data>Text I want to count</data>
</xml>
```

Here is what I have in python

```
import urllib2
import StringIO
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
usock = urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/file.xml') 
xmldoc = minidom.parse(usock)
print xmldoc.toxml()
```

Past This point I have tried using StringIO, ElementTree, and minidom to no success and I have gotten to a point where I'm not sure what else to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

If you are just trying to count the number of times a word appears in an XML document, just read the document as a string and do a count:

```
import urllib2
data = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/file.xml').read()
print data.count('foobar')
```

Otherwise, you can just iterate through the tags you are looking for:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
xml = ET.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/file.xml').read())
for data in xml.getiterator('data'):
    # do something with
    data.text
```

Comment: Its clear from the question he only wants to count words within a particular tag.  You also can't be sure that the word is not actually used as a tag itself, so this approach is clearly wrong

Comment: While this does work for some words, it fails in the presence of XML entities.

Comment: wow I should of got this one. I could possibly use this being the xml response is not to repetitive

Comment: Geez, lots of hating today. The OP does state he's "trying to count the number of times a word appears in an xml document." I changed the count string to not be the same as the tag example he gave.

Comment: @DerekSpringer not hate ... but using a simple count() across an xml document is clearly dangerous and prone to giving you wrong answers ... and you won't know when they are wrong ... hence the the emphatic comment

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple, as far as I can tell:

```
import urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom

usock = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/file.xml') 
xmldoc = minidom.parse(usock)

for element in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('data'):
  print element.firstChild.nodeValue
```

So to count the occurrences of a string, try this (a bit condensed, but I like one-liners):

```
count = sum(element.firstChild.nodeValue.find('substring') for element in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('data'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this help ...

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML

txt = """<xml>
           <title>Info</title>
           <foo>aldfj</foo>
           <data>Text I want to count</data>
         </xml>"""

# this will give us the contents of the data tag.
data = XML(txt).find("data").text

# ... so here we could do whatever we want
print data
```

Comment: No, it only gets one specific text, not all text nodes.

Comment: I'm not doing all of his homework ... from there he can figure out to use findall himself ...

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the string 'count' with whatever word you want to count.  If you want to count phrases, then you'll have to adapt this code as this is for word counting.  But anyway, the answer to how to get at all the embedded text is `XML('<your xml string here>').itertext()`

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML
from re import findall

txt = """<xml>
        <title>Info</title>
        <foo>aldfj</foo>
        <data>Text I want to count</data>
    </xml>"""

sum([len(filter(lambda w: w == 'count', findall('\w+', t))) for t in XML(txt).itertext()])
```