# How to parse XML using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having trouble **parse this response**:

```
    <DadosEstoque>
        <ProtocoloEstoque>45ccd004-4c89-4c73</ProtocoloEstoque>
        <CodigoProduto>000197</CodigoProduto>
    </DadosEstoque>
    <DadosEstoque>
        <ProtocoloEstoque>45ccd01212</ProtocoloEstoque>
        <CodigoProduto>000200</CodigoProduto>
    </DadosEstoque>
```

Python:

```
r = requests.post("http://......asmx/EstoquesDisponiveis", data = {"ChaveIdentificacao":"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    for abbr in soup.findAll('CodigoProduto'):
        productcode = abbr.string
```

I Want:
*print 'CodigoProduto: ' + productcode*

Python no returns nothing... **NO OUTPUT**.

**UPDATE!!! Solved**

```
import urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom

usock = urllib2.urlopen('http://ws......') 
xmldoc = minidom.parse(usock)

staffs = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("DadosEstoque")
for staff in staffs:
        sku = staff.getElementsByTagName("CodigoProduto")[0]
        protocolo = staff.getElementsByTagName("ProtocoloEstoque")[0]
        print("SKU: %s" % (sku.firstChild.data))
        print("PROTOCOLO: %s" % (protocolo.firstChild.data))
```

Comment: How about you change it to `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "xml")`?

Comment: print r.text shows the xml, but with BeautifulSoup(r.text, "xml") i'm getting the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem based in this topics [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668288),[2](http://www.mkyong.com/python/python-read-xml-file-dom-example/). Thx guys!

```
import urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom

usock = urllib2.urlopen('http://ws......') 
xmldoc = minidom.parse(usock)

staffs = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("DadosEstoque")
for staff in staffs:
        sku = staff.getElementsByTagName("CodigoProduto")[0]
        protocolo = staff.getElementsByTagName("ProtocoloEstoque")[0]
        print("SKU: %s" % (sku.firstChild.data))
        print("PROTOCOLO: %s" % (protocolo.firstChild.data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an XML file into the HTML parser. You need to supply an XML parser. If you have lxml installed, then the following should work:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "xml")
>>> soup.findAll('CodigoProduto')
[<CodigoProduto>000197</CodigoProduto>]
```

For more information on BeautifulSoup parsers, just [check the help](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: print r.text  shows the xml, but with BeautifulSoup(r.text,  "xml")  i'm getting the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'.